# Any risks down the line choosing maths vs. stats PhD programme?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, career-path, advisor

It seems funding for a PhD (at least in the UK) is a lot easier to get for a PhD in statistics rather then maths. Provided one can find a supervisor who has the background and research interestes that would allow one to keep extending ones pure mathematical toolbox are there any major risks in going for a PhD in stats ?

It seems to me that at any given stage there is a lot of flexibility with a degree in mathematics. (For instance people seem very open minded to let a maths MSc do a stats PhD). Is it justified to be worried about losing this flexibility if one opts for the PhD in stats rather then maths?

In particular I am worried about whether it is possible to transition back to the maths departement for a postdoctoral position or something equivalent. So essentially I want to know whether one will get branded to an extend that would make it difficult to go on and work in pure mathematics after the PhD.

Comment: Looks much better. There are a few mathematicians on this site who can hopefully provide a good answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Provided one can find a supervisor who has the background and research interestes that would allow one to keep extending ones pure mathematical toolbox are there any major risks in going for a PhD in stats?

There's a small risk, but it can be managed.  The first issue is that you need to make the mathematical content of your work very clear, for example by publishing in journals that could be considered both math journals and statistics journals (e.g., IMS journals).  However, if you're interested in math departments I assume you'd be doing that anyway.

The slightly more subtle issue is how mathematicians view statisticians.  There's sometimes a mild prejudice that people in mathematical statistics are overly specialized and outside of the mainstream of mathematics.  For example, it's possible to get a Ph.D. in mathematical statistics while having considerably less breadth of mathematical background than would be considered acceptable for a math grad student.  (Of course, the flip side is that you are expected to know other things instead.)  There's sometimes a fear that a statistician would be unlikely to talk much with other math department members, or might be unwilling or unable to teach anything but statistics.

Plenty of statisticians have found jobs in math departments, so I don't want to be discouraging.  However, I'd recommend focusing on mathematical breadth.  For example, if you work with people in combinatorics or algebra, then it will be clear to everyone why a math department is a natural fit.  If you talk only to statisticians, it will be less clear.  It can still work out even then, but generally when the department either has a thriving statistics group or has decided they really need a statistician (and either way this cuts down on the flexibility of your job search).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer about stats/maths directly, but in general the department you get your PhD in matters less than who it is with. This is especially true in places like the UK were there is no course work component. In my current department, psychology, about 50% of the faculty, including myself, did not get our PhD from Psychology departments. That said, if you are only willing to teach in a Maths department, then you should probably go to a Maths department. If you are willing to teach in either Maths or Stats, then it doesn't matter too much.